# Angularjs: pass a parameter to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have link in my `html` page like this

```
<td><a href="#/reg_det">  Drivers  </a></td>.
```

I need to send a parameter like `{{Registration.publicId}}` to my angular controller when user clicks on this link, but i don't know how can i do it?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Please explain use case in more detail. Approach would depend on what you need to accomplish. Suggest reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through $scope.

Read more about it here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Unless you go about it with ng-click: (example)

```
<button ng-click="yourFunction(Registration.publicId)">Drivers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `$routeParams`

[Here is a good tutorial on How to use $routeParams](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/angularjs-novice-to-ninja/preview/using-routeparams-in-the-controller-6e0d5e2)

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ng-click` to activate a function in your controller with data held in your app, allowing you to update your `$scope` variable.

Here's a simplified example:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head></head>
    <body ng-app="my-angular-app">
        <div ng-controller="my-controller">
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="someFunction(Registration.publicId)">Drivers</a></td>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have a function in your controller to handle this, though.

You could alternatively use [routeParams](http://blog.hfarazm.com/angularjs-routeparams/) to achieve this without `ng-click`.